# Vaadin 8 Grid cell editors

Tags: grid, vaadin8

I have a question on using Vaadin Grid with customized cell editor. A couple of use cases.

In the first case, suppose the cell value is a date, I would like to have an in-cell editor that would pop up a Calendar component for the user to select the date from/to.

In the second case, suppose the cell value comes from a reference table, I like to have a ListSelect containing all the possible values for the user to choose from. These use cases are very common and Java FX seems to have working samples.

I found out that once a Grid is instantiated with a predefined class, the moment the following call is made, the columnId (a Map) in the Grid is populated. Meaning all columns with properties in the classes are added to the Grid.

```
Grid <Person> personGrid = new Grid<>();
```

But the page https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/components/components-grid.html shows me that after you call setItems() with a list of persons, you still can go ahead and call addColumn, which in my situation ran into an example saying the column has already been added.

My question is actually how do I associate a ListSelect when the user clicks on the cell where I want to display the values. When I tried setEditorComponent with an HasValue, it didn't seem to work. It was still using the default underlying TextEdit for the editor.

The code sample below has not been re-factored. It is just a prototype. The intention is so that when I want to stand up common reference table maintenance capabilities, I'd use reflection to populate the Grid. But for some fields that are foreign keys, I'd like to use a new SQL to fetch all the possible values to display the selected values. The below code setEditorComponent is a test code that I attempted to set the editor for that column the customized MyListSelect, which just extends from Component and implements the HasValue interface. But this didn't work for me.

Please guide!

```
    void populateGrid(String tableName, VerticalLayout mLayout) { 

    ArrayList<TabSheet> outList = new ArrayList<TabSheet>();
    findTabSheet((ComponentContainer) mLayout, outList); 
    setContent(mLayout);
    TabSheet sheet = outList.get(0);  
    VerticalLayout tab1 = new VerticalLayout(); 
    sheet.addTab(tab1, tableName, null); 
    tab1.setVisible(true);
    WCECDomainTable theDomainTable = domainTableHash.get(tableName);
    Class domainTableClass;
    try {
        domainTableClass = Class.forName(theDomainTable.getEntityName());
        JpaRepository repo = (JpaRepository) theDomainTable.getRepoProxy();
        ColumnToRendererAssociation [] fieldNames2 = extractProperty(domainTableClass);

        Grid theGrid = new Grid<>(domainTableClass);
        tab1.addComponent(theGrid);
        theGrid.setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        theGrid.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        theGrid.setVisible(true);

        //theGrid.setColumns(fieldNames2); 

        theGrid.setItems(repo.findAll());   
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames2.length; i++) {
            Component editorComponent = fieldNames2[i].getEditorComponent();
            if (editorComponent != null) {
                theGrid.removeColumn(fieldNames2[i].getPropertyName());
                theGrid.addColumn(fieldNames2[i].getPropertyName()).setEditorComponent((MyListSelect) editorComponent);
            }
        }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

ColumnToRendererAssociation [] extractProperty(Class aClass) {
    List<Field> currentClassFields = (List) Lists.newArrayList(aClass.getDeclaredFields());
    ColumnToRendererAssociation fieldNames[] = new ColumnToRendererAssociation[currentClassFields.size()];
    int actualSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        if (!currentClassFields.get(i).getName().equals("serialVersionUID")) {
            MyListSelect listSelect = new MyListSelect();
            listSelect.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
            listSelect.setHeight(82, Unit.PIXELS);  
            //listSelect.addValueChangeListener(this);
            Field aField = currentClassFields.get(i);

            String packageName = "";
            if (aField.getType().getPackage() != null) {
                packageName = aField.getType().getPackage().getName();
            }
            if (packageName.indexOf("org.wcec.retreat") >= 0) {
                fieldNames[j] = new ColumnToRendererAssociation(currentClassFields.get(i).getName(), (Component) listSelect);
            } else {
                fieldNames[j] = new ColumnToRendererAssociation(currentClassFields.get(i).getName(), null);
            } 

            j++;
            actualSize = j;
        }
    }
    ColumnToRendererAssociation fieldNames2[] = new ColumnToRendererAssociation[actualSize];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        if (fieldNames[i] != null) { 
            fieldNames2[j] = fieldNames[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return fieldNames2;
}
```

Comment: When you call `new Grid<>(domainTableClass)` then your `Grid` initializes its columns with the bean properties of that class. That means adding a column with the same property name afterwards will give that mentioned error. So you could either do not specify a `Class` as constructor parameter (and define the columns via `addColumn`) or use `grid.getColumn(String)` to get the column and adapt it.

Comment: Thanks so much Steffen! If I do not specify the Class associated with the data in the Grid, I don't seem to be able to use the setItems API to populate the Grid, correct? That means I need to write code to populate them individually?

Comment: `setItems` should be independant from that `Class` argument in constructor, as far as I know.